# About free for user declaration

Tags: 14.04

Where is declared that Ubuntu is free for users? I mean officially declaration where Ubuntu mention that desktop version is free to use, not commercial.

Answer (score 2):

It says so on the [main Ubuntu webpage](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop). A strange place for it, granted, but there you go:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is free for all, and open-source, but you can buy a premium customer service to Canonical, and some advanced software are not free (but still open-source).

Answer (score 0):

On the about pages you can read about everything regarding licensing free and OSS (open-source software):

- http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu
- http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy